# Different seeds on different render layers

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, render-layers

Under the *Render Properties* tab there is a setting to change the seed used for ray tracing.  Is there a way to use different seeds on different render layers?

[image: seed setting in the sampling section of the render tab of the properties window]

I know this is possible using multiple scenes instead of render layers and linking objects, but that is pretty cumbersome.

Comment: How about driving it with single property ID object 'Scene' data_path `render.layers.active_index`  gives a different value depending on which renderlayer is active

Comment: @batFINGER I tried putting `#render.layers.active_index` in the seed box, but the seed seems to be the same for the two layers.

Comment: @batFINGER `active_index` seems to be the selected render layer, not the one currently rendering.

Comment: In conjunction with http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8863/how-do-i-render-specific-render-layers-using-python write script to render layers individually with differing  seed values set for each.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a full copy of the scene into another and select other seed in it. You are gonna need a new scene for every diferent seed. Them, in compositing you can select scenes and layers in the render nodes.