# Render Layer ID for material in Cycles?

Tags: render-layers

[image]

It would be useful for some particular final render to have multiple render layers where the render can choose material features based on a Render ID.   Object ID is a similar precedent.

Is that feature or facsimile already present?

Assuming render layer pre needs to be registered and run

**Python Preliminary**

```
import bpy

def renderID2016():

m = bpy.data.materials['UVObject']
n = m.node_tree.nodes
v = n.get("Value")
v.outputs[0].default_value = 5


renderID2016()
```

Will consider frame_change and render_pre.

Can the materials know the current render layer name or render layer index?

[image]

We can set a property for some random variable.  Not for any member the variable scene.render.layers  .

**Failed Attempts**

[image]

Image above.  If you use an Cycles materials as emission,  the setting above affects the Cycles lights.  Sun Lamps, Point Lights, and these automatic lights are not affected.

Comment: There may be a way to do this with drivers, I'm not sure.  I am also [looking for a way to drive something based on the render layer](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/41875/different-seeds-on-different-render-layers).